# Not able to initialise a cloned repo for git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

I have some legacy visual studio projects that need to brought under source control and they seem ideal candidates for the git flow workflow.  However, I have hit a problem that I can't create any git flow branches as the resulting repo shows as not being git flow initialised and wonder if I've missed a step or done something incorrectly.

The steps I've used are as follows:

1. Create  a git repo using Visual Studio (mostly VS2015 but some with VS2012 but the problem exists regardless of version.)
2. Open the repo in Source Tree (v1.7.0.32509) and hit the *Git Flow* toolbar button, accepting the default settings. This adds the expected **develop** branch in addition to the existing master branch.
3. Launch the terminal from within Source Tree and create a bare clone of the repo to act as a central team repo (I don't see an option to do this within the Source Tree menus but I'm happy with the command line :) .)

   git clone --bare [current repo path] [bare repo path.git]
4. Clone the new bare repo for a local working copy.  This has a branch of  **develop** and remote branches of **origin/master** **origin/develop** **origin/HEAD**

Opening the *original repo ins Source Tree, the one from which the bare repo is created, and selecting Git Flow give the options to *Start a new feature*, *Start a new release*, etc, as expected.

The problem comes after opening the new local working copy *create from* the bare clone.  Source Tree doesn't recognise it as a git flow repository as it's missing a local master branch:

[image: full error message from Source Tree that the master branch is missing]

Adding a local master branch with:

```
git branch master origin/master
```

and then reinitialising the local repo for git flow again *seems* to solve the problem.

My question is are these additional steps usual or have I misunderstood something?  I can't believe this is the normal process as git is usually simpler than that :-)

Comment: I've accepted my own answer as it solves my immediate problem (and it's the only one at present), but if anyone sees this and has a better answer/explanation then I'll gladly change it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more digging I found this is a [known/open issue with gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/121) for which there might not be a fix (?) but there is a workaround.

Skipping step 2 in my question, so I create the bare repo before initialising the source repo for git flow stops the error happening.  Clones of the bare repo are able to be initialised with git flow without any pre-steps being carried out.